Galvanic corrosion with brazing dissimilar metals
I have a project which involves joining mild steel coupling nuts to a much larger aluminum piece. Of course, directly welding these 2 very different metals together is a no-no. So I was thinking of brazing an intermediate layer between the two.
First, I'd choose a braze that is compatible for both mild steel & aluminum & then braze coat the areas to be joined on both the metals. Then, get both metals aligned & add more braze. Tricky, I expect, as things will move around.
What I'm supposed to end up is a brazing job where the 2 materials don't actually touch each other.
This brazing will be exposed to the outdoors. So, naturally, it'll get wet, soiled, & washed.
My question is now, would there be less Galvanic Corrosion between mild steel & aluminum, if there was this intermediate braze in-between, than if there weren't? Because you do get the idea that they're joined together, so eventually the electrons would just flow unimpeded from the least electronegative metal to the more noble metal in the joint.
But now, I'm realizing something different. Take welding steel to copper. The smallest droplets of water that "shorts" out the steel-to-copper joint (just that small) is all that's needed to have the redox reaction going. Because that's where ions can do their work. So, if we have 2 dissimilar metals sandwiching a braze, then small droplets won't provide the area coverage of the joint for the redox to happen... Well, maybe, if you were to dip the joint in salted water.
So what do you guys think? Is my theory "has to be wet" correct or mistaken? Would I be able to join my steel coupling nuts to my aluminum base, without worrying about Galvanic Corrosion, if I never let them touch on exposed areas?
